# Can I read an external file every set amount of time?

Tags: php, cron

I am writing a script where it checks for an updated version from an external server. I use this code in the config.php file to check for latest version.

```
$data = get_theme_data('http://externalhost.com/style.css');
$latest_version = $data['Version'];
define('LATEST_VERSION', $latest_version);
```

This is fine and I can fetch the latest version (get_theme_data is WordPress function) but the problem is that it will be executed on every single load which I do not want. I also do not want to only check when a form is submitted for example. Alternatively I was looking into some sort of method to cache the result or maybe check the version every set amount of hours? Is such thing possible and how?

Comment: do you have access to `cron` on your server?

Comment: cron job? or wrap the above in some code that only runs say if the hour is 12. on second thoughts that's dumb, just use a cron job

Comment: You need a way to determine when you last performed the check.  Either a database record, or some file saved on the disc.  Something non-volatile.  Then just check the age, if too old, perform your update.  Cron may be an option if you want the update done at fixed time intervals, *if* you have cron available to you on your host.

Comment: I can't do it with cron. Seems like I need to post the date (last time was checked) then maybe use php to compare dates between current date and last checked date and call the file again if the difference is X hours? is that the logic.. Thanks for the idea Orbling

Comment: @Ahmad Fouad why can't you use cron??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, gonna make it easy for you. Store the time you last checked for the update in a file.

```
function checkForUpdate() {
    $file = file_get_contents('./check.cfg', true);
    if ($file === "") {
        $fp = fopen('./check.cfg', 'w+');
        fwrite($fp, time() + 86400);
        fclose($fp);
    }
    if ((int)$file > time()) {
        echo "Do not updatE";
    } else {
        echo "Update";
        $fp = fopen('./check.cfg', 'w+');
        fwrite($fp, time() + 86400);
        fclose($fp);
    }
}
```

You can obviously make this much more secure/efficient if you want to.

Edit: This function will check for update once every day.

Answer (score 1):

A scheduled task like this should be set up as a separate `cron` or `at` job. You can still write everything in PHP, just make a script that runs from the command line and does the updating. Checkout "man crontab" for details, and/or check which scheduling services your server is running.